# Injecting keystrokes on console

Tags: key-bindings, keystrokes

I normally use emacs (on Linux) running in windowing mode. I have bound a number of functions to special keypresses such as `<C-return>` and `<kp-add>`.

Ocasionally, I'm forced to run emacs in a text console, where some of the keypresses cannot be detected.

Is there a way I can tell a console-based emacs, "Pretend I just pressed `<kp-add>`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For keys which a terminal can't even send unmodified (which I suspect is the case with `<kp-add>`), you will need to bind some key which *can* be sent by the terminal.

You can bind a key to the keyboard macro `[kp-add]` in order that the alternative key sequence does whatever `<kp-add>` would have done:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p") (kbd "<kp-add>"))
```

You could even call a macro without a key binding:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(execute-kbd-macro (kbd "<kp-add>"))` <kbd>RET</kbd>

---

Alternatively, you could use `function-key-map` (or the terminal-local `local-function-key-map`) to directly map the key sequences like so:

```
(define-key function-key-map (kbd "C-c p") (kbd "<kp-add>"))
```

in which case Emacs *translates* `C-c p` to `<kp-add>` (as opposed to calling a macro which in turn simulates typing `<kp-add>`).

In practice, both methods ought to do the job.

---

`<C-return>` would be similar, but `C-RET` can be sent via `event-apply-control-modifier` like so:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>c</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd>

If the terminal can send the unmodified key, you can use this approach to send a modified variant. Type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>@</kbd><kbd>C-h</kbd> for the list of supported modifiers.